# cygwin bash script does not get arguments

Tags: bash, cygwin

I associated .sh files with bash.  So I can successfully execute bash scripts from within a Windows command prompt.

The problem is that I am unable to pass command line arguments to my bash scripts from the Winodws command line.

The command line arguments are processed fine if I first go to bash and then execute the scripts their.

So if myscr.sh is

```
echo Args $1, $2
```

Then

```
c:\> myscr.sh a1 a2
Args ,
```

but from bash:

```
$ ./myscr.sh a1 a2
Args a1, a2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The outputs you have pasted seem inconsistent, bash should output "Args a1, a1" and not "Args a1, a2". Why not add echo of `$#` and check the value? Also maybe you could try `bash myscr.sh a1 a2` on Windows and see what you get

Comment: Do you have a #!... line at the beginning of your script ? If yes, could you show us? Because it might no be bash which is running your script in fact, even when you call it from bash. (for example, if your 1st line is #!/usr/bin/python, then calling ./myscr.sh will invoke /usr/bin/python myscr.sh) (sample on Unix server, but same idea with Windows)

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  bash myscr.sh also did not work, and the output of $# is '0'.  Shebang is also included, just omitted for brevity

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem! However, the proposed solution did not work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think solved it. Apparently, `ftype` association did not update the registry.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out to be an association issue.

```
C:\> assoc .sh
.sh=sh_auto_file

C:\> ftype sh_auto_file
sh_auto_file="C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" "%1"
```

That was wrong.  It did not pass the params to bash.  To fix it, just add `%*` to the ftype

```
C:\> ftype sh_auto_file="C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" %1 %*
```

And all params will be passed.